# Serialization java to c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have manged to serialize an arraylist in java using xstream, send it to my c# application via http and then write that to file (just for now).

The serialized data was an arraylist in java. I want to try and re form this arraylist in c# from the xml i have.

I have been looking at http://code.google.com/p/xstream-dot-net/ to do this. Does anyone know if that is the right way to go or is there a better way of reforming the serialized data in c#?

Comment: Maybe you can use SOAP based serialization instead of XML based serialization.

Comment: Serialize an ArrayList to Xml in C# and compare the two files. I would think there are some differences that may provide an answer.

Comment: just in case anyone finds this question and wants an answer. xstream encodes base 64 so all you need to do on the csharp end is read through the generated xml and decode base 64 (terminology might be off here you get the picture)

Comment: If you have discovered an answer to your question, it is perfectly fine to post as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [JSON.NET (Newtonsoft)](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) on the .NET side and [Google's GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) on the java side and it seems to work for Dictionaries, Maps, Sets, Lists, Date, and primitive types with very little configuration involved. Refer to https://github.com/chandru9279/Spikes for it.